# What does Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::fetchOne return on failure (i.e. no rows returned)?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Doesn't seem that failure mode for that function is documented anywhere I've been able to find....

Comment: The docs say "string   fetchOne" and not "mixed", so I wonder if it just returns an empty string? Intuitively I'd expect bool false or an exception, but I don't use Zend_Db. Why don't you try it and see a var_dump of the result on an empty resultset?

Comment: @Fanis: I would have expected `null`, but looks like `false` it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily find it out yourself, do a call on that function with a statement which wont find a value, then just do

> var_dump($myReturnValue);

and it will print the value including the return type :)

Comment: Doh! Looks like it returns false on failure -- makes sense I guess because most (all?) RDBMSs don't have a boolean type (one uses TINYINTs or ENUMs instead).

Answer (score 1):

Although the Zend Abstract class states it returns an array, the PDO returns false on failure. Therefore the return is mixed: array or false

Comment: Why would `fetchOne` return an array?

Comment: Sorry, string not array. My mistake